# SQL: Insert columns from another table with matching object names

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

Table1: 
            vm_name   | host_name
                     vm1      |  server1
                     vm2      |  server1
                     vm3      |  server2

Table 2:    object_id | object_name
                                      1        | server1
                                      2        | vm1
                                      3        | vm3
                                      4        | server2
                                      5        | vm2

I want to add two columns into Table 1 (or make new entire table) that would display the vm_name, object_id, host_name, object_id. I also want to change the object_id column names to vm_id and host_id.

Output table would look like this: 
           vm_name   | vm_id | host_name | host_id
                    vm1      |     2      |  server1        |   1
                    vm2      |     5       |  server1       |   1
                    vm3      |      3      |  server2       |   4

Any ideas on how to go about doing this?
So far, I have I'm using join to match up: vm_name | object_id

```
SELECT table1.vm_name, table2.object_id
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.vm_name = table2.object_name
ORDER BY table1.vm_name;
```

But how do I add both columns simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join it back to `table2` again:

```
select t1.vm_name, 
       t2.object_id as vm_id,
       t1.host_name,
       t3.object_id as host_id
from table1 t1
       join table2 t2 on t1.vm_name = t2.object_name
       join table2 t3 on t1.host_name = t3.object_name
order by t1.vm_name
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/51829/1)